# How can I set an option per buffer, not just per window?

Tags: vim

I use `foldmethod=syntax` for most languages. One issue is that when going into insert mode, it reparses the syntax, and will get rid of the state of folds if any open parentheses/brackets/etc are introduced.

There is a solution here

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text

```
augroup folding
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertEnter *
    \ if !exists('w:last_fdm') |
    \ let w:last_fdm=&foldmethod |
    \ setlocal foldmethod=manual |
    \ endif
  autocmd InsertLeave,WinLeave *
    \ if exists('w:last_fdm') |
    \ let &l:foldmethod=w:last_fdm |
    \ unlet w:last_fdm |
    \ endif
```

augroup END

But if I have the same file opened in another window, it will not change the `foldmethod` of that window. And thus break folds, and still be slow.

How can I fix this? Can I set the `foldmethod` option per buffer instead so that it applies to all windows?

Comment: May I suggest the more reliable, more consistent and less computationally expensive `indent` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'foldmethod'` option is per-window, and that cannot be changed. The problem is that your autocmd only modifies the *current window*'s option values, but you want that processing done for *all* windows. That can be done, though it is more involved.

- Loop through all windows: `for winNr in range(1, winnr('$'))`
- Instead of `let w:last_fdm`, use `:call setwinvar()`.
- Likewise, `:setlocal` can be replaced with `:call setwinvar()`, using the special `&foldmethod` notation for a window-local option.

vim code:

```
function! s:InsertEnter()
  for n in range(1, winnr('$'))
    :call setwinvar(n, "last_fdm", getwinvar(n, "&foldmethod"))
    :call setwinvar(n, "&foldmethod", "manual")
  endfor
endfunction

function! s:InsertLeave()
  if exists('w:last_fdm')
    for n in range(1, winnr('$'))
      :call setwinvar(n, "&foldmethod", getwinvar(n, "last_fdm"))
    endfor
    unlet w:last_fdm
  endif
endfunction

augroup folding
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertEnter * :call <SID>InsertEnter()
  autocmd InsertLeave,WinLeave * :call <SID>InsertLeave()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setlocal` instead of `set` to make it buffer specific.

```
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

Take a look at `:help setlocal`

Comment: that's what I'm using. I've updated the question with the code I'm using from the link.